# Can we say a C# class is automatically nullable?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Look at this C# code (.Net6 Console project):

```
class MyClass {
  public int a;
  public int b;
}
```

Now, look at this declaration:

```
MyClass obj = null;
```

At this step, I have no error and no warnings. So I suppose MyClass is a nullable type ? Am I Wrong at this step ?

Now look at this code:

```
var sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
var deser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MyClass obj2 = (MyClass) deser.Deserialize(sr);
```

It works but I have a CS8600 warning.

If I want to remove this warning I have to write this:

```
MyClass? obj2 = (MyClass?) deser.Deserialize(sr);
```

So MyClass is nullable or not nullable ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `MyClass obj = null;` absolutely does give you a warning though. (*CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type* to be specific)

Comment: https://endjin.com/blog/2020/04/dotnet-csharp-8-nullable-references-non-nullable-is-the-new-default

Comment: `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` returns an `object?` so it explicitly can return a null - hence the warning.

Comment: Are the two codes are written in the same file or project? These behaviours depend on whether you have `#nullable enable` or the nullable reference types setting in your csproj file.

Comment: Is the target framework maybe .NET 5?

Comment: The *reference* can be nullable.  That was always true, you now have syntax available to state that a reference is never null.  And the compiler will then help you get it right.  You'd better [rtfm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Comment: Ultimately, virtually every serialiser is going to return a nullable type since the serialisation process can fail, so you should be checking for nulls.

Comment: All classes (reference types) are nullable "under the hood." The nullability annotation with the question mark helps you find all places in code where a null assignment may happen unintentionally. The compiler runs a sophisticated static analysis to warn you about possible null assignments, but the code it generates is going to run the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always assign `null` to a reference type; however, whether you get a warning depends on whether you are in a [Nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) and whether you typed it as nullable (`?`).

A nullable reference type is the same type as the non nullable one. I.e.:

```cs
string? nullable = "hello";
string nonNullable = "world";

if (nullable.GetType() == nonNullable.GetType()) {
    // Does always execute this
    Console.WriteLine("same type");
}

if (nullable.GetType() == typeof(string)) {
    // Does always execute this
    Console.WriteLine("same type");
}

// typeof(string?) generates
// Error CS8639 The typeof operator cannot be used on a nullable reference type.
```

The nullability is only a hint for the compiler to allow it analyzing the control flow and to detect possible null references enabling it to issue corresponding warnings.

Starting with .NET 6 the nullable context is enabled by default but you can still disable it, e.g., with `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in the project file. In previous .NET versions you had to enable it with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`.

You can also enable or disable the nullable context for specific code regions with the `#nullable` directive.